# Find first non-blank cell in column that meets criteria in another column

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I've compiled multiple spreadsheets containing sporadic employee information, and I'm now trying to consolidate all of the information to remove duplicates and blanks. The formula below is my starting point, but if the first cell that meets that criteria is blank, it returns a blank. I want it to find the next cell that meets that criteria but has a value.

=INDEX(Working!C:C,MATCH($A3,Working!$B:$B,0))

Below is what the Working tab looks like, which contains the master list of data including blanks and duplicates. Working!C:C is the list of last names; $A3 is the Employee ID I'm hoping to retrieve data for, and Working!$B:$B is the list of Employee IDs. I'll be doing this for many columns, so to illustrate this, in the table example below I've shown that Column D is the phone number. Any help you can provide is appreciated!

Column B-------C-------D

---------287-----Doe----blank

---------287-----blank---333-333-3333

---------287-----Doe----blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX(Working!C$1:C$100,MATCH(1,($A3 = Working!$B$1:$B$100)*(Working!C$1:C$100<>""),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Please note that with an array formula the references need to be the smallest range possible that covers the dataset.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott! It's still picking up the first cell though, which sometimes is blank. Can you tell me what the (1, part of the equation is doing, as well as the multiplier *? Maybe that will help me figure out what its missing?

Comment: @KRD sorry see edit.  It is True/FALSE resolves to 1/0 respectively so we are looking for when B = A and C is not "".

Comment: Still no luck. It's producing a zero for blanks instead of finding the next instance of that employee ID to find the actual value.

Comment: @KRD it is working for me,  Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?  Did Excel put `{}` around the formula.  Are the Cells blank, or do they have a space in them or other non-printable characters?  It must be blank, or a formula that returns `""`.

Comment: you're right- they weren't actually blank. Thank you thank you!!